# Global "window" object

Tags: javascript, node.js

The global `window` object stores properties specific to the environment (for example, `window.innerHeight`).

But if we print `window` to the console, we will see the properties highlighted in a different color.

[image]

These include `Array`, `Object`, and so on, although i thought they are internal objects.

I have a few questions:

1. What are these "implicit" properties?
2. Where do JS boundaries end and environment begin?
3. Can I refer to `Array` in Node.js, for example?

Thank you.

Comment: [JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide)

Comment: The different colour in highlighting are the difference between **enumerated** and **non-enumerated** items in window. What I mean by that is that there are some properties in window that are not keys. `Object.keys(window).includes('XMLHttpRequest')===false` whereas `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).includes('XMLHttpRequest')===true`.. in short, JavaScript is huge and has a unique yet strange environment

Comment: as for what I meant by *enumerable* check [this](https://howchoo.com/javascript/enumerable-properties-in-javascript)

Comment: In the early days of Javascript, there was one master global symbol and everything that was available in the global scope was a property of that master global.  In the browser, that master global is the `window` object.  Thus, you see many things on the `window` object that are available globally like the `Array` constructor.  I would guess that this is a side effect of that fact that Javascript was first designed to run in a browser and was not initially a completely stand-alone language with a stand-alone specification.

Comment: @TheBombSquad, Thank you! 
But i don't understand something yet: if functions like `XMLHttpRequest` are part of the environment, then what is the javascript at the lower level? Just provides the syntax for interacting with the environment api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the early days of Javascript, there was one master global symbol and everything that was available in the global scope whether it was part of the language itself or part of the browser environment was a property of that master global.

In the browser, that master global is the `window` object. Thus, you see many things on the `window` object that are available globally like the `Array` constructor.

I would guess that this is a side effect of that fact that Javascript was first designed to run in a browser and was not initially a completely stand-alone language with a stand-alone specification.

More recent revisions to the language specification are not adding some new things to the `window` object any more.  For example, when you declare an ES6 `class` such as:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(greeting) {
        this.greeting = greeting;
    }
}
```

You will not find `Foo` on the `window` object even though it may be globally available in the browser.

As others have said, the color difference in the debug output has to do with whether the symbols are enumerable or not which is a technical distinction on whether the property shows up in something like `Object.keys()` or a `for/in` loop.  The property is still there and is accessible either way.

Comment: I did it. Сan i ask you to upvote my question to remove a negative number.